How to integrate dynamodb with pypspark or databricks?
I am trying to connect amazon dynamodb with pyspark and i am following this documentation to do so https://github.com/audienceproject/spark-dynamodb but in output i am not getting any data in my table. This is my code to connect dynamodb with pyspark
import os


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"] ="myAccessKey" 
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "mySecretKey"
print(os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"])
print(os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SQL Server to PySpark") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages","com.audienceproject:spark-dynamodb_2.12:1.1.2") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Load a DataFrame from a Dynamo table. Only incurs the cost of a single scan for schema inference.
df  = spark.read.option("tableName", "test_db") \
                     .format("dynamodb") \
                     .load()
df.show()

In output i am getting this 
24/10/07 12:05:19 WARN Utils: Your hostname, arvind-ThinkPad-T480s resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.77 instead (on interface wlp61s0)
24/10/07 12:05:19 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/arvind/Desktop/pyspark/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3/jars/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/arvind/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/arvind/.ivy2/jars
com.audienceproject#spark-dynamodb_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-5377cf76-fb30-4e81-9f86-88e9a7474777;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found com.audienceproject#spark-dynamodb_2.12;1.1.2 in central
        found com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-sts;1.11.678 in central
        found com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-core;1.11.678 in central
        found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 in central
        found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.5.9 in central
        found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.4.11 in central
        found commons-codec#commons-codec;1.11 in central
        found software.amazon.ion#ion-java;1.0.2 in central
        found com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.6.7.3 in central
        found com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.6.0 in central
        found com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.6.7 in central
        found com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat#jackson-dataformat-cbor;2.6.7 in central
        found joda-time#joda-time;2.8.1 in central
        found com.amazonaws#jmespath-java;1.11.678 in central
        found com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-dynamodb;1.11.678 in central
        found com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-s3;1.11.678 in central
        found com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-kms;1.11.678 in central
        found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.25 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 602ms :: artifacts dl 28ms
        :: modules in use:
        com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-core;1.11.678 from central in [default]
        com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-dynamodb;1.11.678 from central in [default]
        com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-kms;1.11.678 from central in [default]
        com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-s3;1.11.678 from central in [default]
        com.amazonaws#aws-java-sdk-sts;1.11.678 from central in [default]
        com.amazonaws#jmespath-java;1.11.678 from central in [default]
        com.audienceproject#spark-dynamodb_2.12;1.1.2 from central in [default]
        com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.6.0 from central in [default]
        com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.6.7 from central in [default]
        com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.6.7.3 from central in [default]
        com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat#jackson-dataformat-cbor;2.6.7 from central in [default]
        commons-codec#commons-codec;1.11 from central in [default]
        commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 from central in [default]
        joda-time#joda-time;2.8.1 from central in [default]
        org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.5.9 from central in [default]
        org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.4.11 from central in [default]
        org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.25 from central in [default]
        software.amazon.ion#ion-java;1.0.2 from central in [default]
        :: evicted modules:
        commons-logging#commons-logging;1.2 by [commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3] in [default]
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   19  |   0   |   0   |   1   ||   18  |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-5377cf76-fb30-4e81-9f86-88e9a7474777
        confs: [default]
        0 artifacts copied, 18 already retrieved (0kB/16ms)
24/10/07 12:05:20 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
24/10/07 12:05:31 WARN V2ScanPartitioningAndOrdering: Spark ignores the partitioning OutputPartitioning. Please use KeyGroupedPartitioning for better performance

++
| |
++
++
why i am getting this issue is this driver issue?
Also if there is another way to connect then please explain that.

Try adding the S3 Access key and S3 Secret Key in the Spark Session Config:
# Configure Spark session
conf = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SQL Server to PySpark") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.audienceproject:spark-dynamodb_2.12:1.1.2") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"]) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])

Also check if the AWS IAM role attached to the service you are running, has all the required access.

spark lifts the secrets from the env vars, as does the default s3a authenticator chain. And the fs.s3a settings aren't used by the AWS SDK's dynamodb client, which needs its own configuration. which is a lot more than just the credentials
